# Do both أهل الكتاب and أُوتُواْ ٱلۡكِتَـٰبَ refer to People of the Book?

Tags: tafseer, non-muslim, ahlul-kitab

Are both the phrase

## أهل الكتاب

and

## ٱلَّذِينَ أُوتُواْ ٱلۡكِتَـٰبَ

referring to People of the Book in Qur'an?

Answer (score -2):

The 2 phrases are the same and refer to (Jewishs and Christians)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. This looks more like a comment than an answer we require answers here to be well elaborated, focussed on answering the actual question and claims to be supported by evidences (See [answer]).